# How to pronounce "404 Not Found"

Tags: pronunciation

How do we pronounce the http status code *404 not found*: *four hundreds and four*, *four-zero-four* or *four-four*? We usually use 200, 201, 302, 401, 403, 404, 412, 500. I have read [How to pronounce "720p" and "1080p"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32563).

Comment: On [youtube](http://www.youtube.com), search for:  404 podcast, where they usually say four-oh-four a few times in the first half-minute of each show

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is pronounced as ***Four-o-Four not found*** .

Other codes can be pronounced as Dusty mentioned. Along with that:

- 720p = Seven Twenty P
- 1080 = Ten Eighty P
- 201  = Two O One
- 302  = Three O Two

These are just the common pronunciation notations. I hope this helps.

Comment: Four oh four.  But isn't it true that saying "oh" for "zero" is less common in the UK than in the US?

Comment: @GEdgar: In the UK 'oh' is far more common than 'zero' for things like telephone numbers.

Answer (score 8):

It's normally pronounced *four-oh-four*. The same pattern would apply to the rest of the status codes you listed except for:

> 200 - *two hundred*
>
> 412 - *four twelve*
>
> 500 - *five hundred*